# Calculate a Running Monthly Average in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

We want to create a data-set which shows the monthly average count in our equipment table broken down by it's status: Active, Scrapped, New.

The more I ponder this it seems that the only way to accomplish this is to first create a container temp table and evaluate each record using a cursor.

Can this be accomplished without a temp table?

The following just shows the fields we're working with:

```
SELECT a1.statusdate, a1.CreateDate,
RunningTotalActive = count([status]='Active'),
RunningTotalScrapped = count([status]='Scrapped'),
NewEquipment = count(Month(a1.CreateDate) ) 
FROM dbo.Equipment AS a1
INNER JOIN dbo.Equipment AS a2
ON a2.statusdate <= a1.CreateDate
GROUP BY a1.statusdate
ORDER BY a1.statusdate desc
```

Comment: sample data, and expected results would help with this kind of question.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: @John MS SS 2012 - thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a few SWAGs about your data, but the idea is to average the sums over simple counts by month; using CTEs.

```
; WITH A AS (
    SELECT a1.statusdate,
    Active = CASE a1.[status] WHEN 'Active' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    Scrapped = CASE a1.[status] WHEN 'Scrapped' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    New = CASE WHEN a2.statusdate = a1.CreateDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END --Guessing here that "new" means status date and create date are the same
    FROM dbo.Equipment AS a1
    INNER JOIN dbo.Equipment AS a2
    ON a2.statusdate <= a1.CreateDate --"status" can be older than "create" for a piece of equipment? Not sure I understand this criteria. May need sample data.
), B AS (
    SELECT Y = DATEPART(YEAR, statusdate)
    , M = DATEPART(MONTH, statusdate)
    , SumActive = SUM(Active)
    , SumScrapped = SUM(Scrapped)
    , SumNew = SUM(New)
    FROM A
    GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, statusdate), DATEPART(MONTH, statusdate)
) 
SELECT Y, M,
    RunningTotalActive = AVG(SumActive)OVER(PARTITION BY Y,M ORDER BY Y,M),
    RunningTotalScrapped = AVG(SumScrapped)OVER(PARTITION BY Y,M ORDER BY Y,M),
    NewEquipment = AVG(SumNew)OVER(PARTITION BY Y,M ORDER BY Y,M)
FROM B;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show some sample data?
I had modified your script following my understanding. Can you try it?

```
    SELECT YEAR(a1.statusdate) AS yr,MONTH(a1.statusdate) AS mon,
           RunningTotalActive = count(CASE WHEN a1.[status]='Active' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ), -- or SUM(CASE WHEN [status]='Active' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ),
           RunningTotalScrapped = count(CASE WHEN a1.[status]='Scrapped' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END),
           NewEquipment = count(CASE WHEN YEAR(a1.CreateDate)*12+ MONTH(a1.CreateDate)= YEAR(a1.statusdate)*12+ MONTH(a1.statusdate)) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END )
    FROM dbo.Equipment AS a1
    GROUP BY YEAR(a1.statusdate),MONTH(a1.statusdate) 
    ORDER BY YEAR(a1.statusdate),MONTH(a1.statusdate) DESC
```